# Spring security integration with open id in grails

Tags: security, grails, spring-security, openid, google-openid

I am working on Integrating spring security with openId for my grails Application using springsecurity core and springsecurity openid plugins. I have integrated it, and it works well but I need to access the email for the logged in person. How can I get that, all that I am able to access is a token which is used for identifying the person.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Ian Roberts.
He gives me this reply,Which exactly solves my problem.
**His reply was:**

As it happens I implemented exactly this in one of my applications
yesterday :-)  Unfortunately it's not an open-source app so I can't just
point you at my code but I can explain what I did.

The spring-security-openid plugin supports the "attribute exchange"
mechanism of OpenID, although the support is not documented much (if at
all).  How well it works depends on the provider at the far end but this
at least worked for me using Google and Yahoo.

In order to request the email address from the provider you need to add
the following to Config.groovy:

grails.plugins.springsecurity.openid.registration.requiredAttributes.email
= "http://axschema.org/contact/email"

Now to wire that into your user registration process you need an email
field in your S2 user domain class, and you need to edit the generated
OpenIdController.groovy in a few places.

- add an email property to the OpenIdRegisterCommand
- in the createAccount action there's a line
  "if(!createNewAccount(...))" which passes the username, password and
  openid as parameters.  Change this along with the method definition to
  pass the whole command object instead of just these two fields.
- in createNewAccount pass the email value forward from the command
  object to the User domain object constructor.

And finally add an input field for email to your
grails-app/views/openId/createAccount.gsp.

You can do the same with other attributes such as full name.

grails.plugins.springsecurity.openid.registration.requiredAttributes.fullname
= "http://axschema.org/namePerson"

The important thing to wire it together is that the thing after the last
dot following requiredAttributes (fullname in this example) must match
the name of the property on the OpenIdRegisterCommand.

Regards
Charu Jain

Comment: I have verified that this works, and have a little more info. The steps above will not only get the email but will associate it with new users when created. If you just want to access the email from within the session during the authentication process (ie: from within the OpenIdController createAccount function) you may do so by using the session[OIAFH.LAST_OPENID_ATTRIBUTES] String object.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the springsecurity openid plugin, but when using springsecurity core you can expose additional information about the current user by implmenting a custom `UserDetails`. In my app, I added this implementation, so that I can show the `name` property of logged-in users. You'll need to change this slightly, so that the email address is exposed instead

```
/**
 * Custom implementation of UserDetails that exposes the user's name
 * http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html
 */
class CustomUserDetails extends GrailsUser {

    // additional property
    final String name

    CustomUserDetails(String username,
                      String password,
                      boolean enabled,
                      boolean accountNonExpired,
                      boolean credentialsNonExpired,
                      boolean accountNonLocked,
                      Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                      long id,
                      String displayName) {

        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, id)
        this.name = displayName
    }
}
```

You then need to create a custom implementation of `UserDetailsService` which returns instances of the class above

```
class UserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {

    /**
     * Some Spring Security classes (e.g. RoleHierarchyVoter) expect at least one role, so
     * we give a user with no granted roles this one which gets past that restriction but
     * doesn't grant anything.
     */
    static final List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) {
        return loadUserByUsername(username)
    }

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User.withTransaction { status ->

            User user = User.findByUsername(username)
            if (!user) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)
            }

            def authorities = user.authorities.collect {new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority)}
            return new CustomUserDetails(
                    user.username,
                    user.password,
                    user.enabled,
                    !user.accountExpired,
                    !user.passwordExpired,
                    !user.accountLocked,
                    authorities ?: NO_ROLES,
                    user.id,
                    user.name)
        }
    }
}
```

You need to register an instance of this class as a Spring bean named `userDetailsService`. I did this by adding the following to `Resources.groovy`

```
userDetailsService(UserDetailsService)
```